# How to go back to an earlier screen in install4j?

Tags: install4j

Basically, I want to go to the Installation Components screen, after one installation. Just like the dbca setup wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the ID of the screen you want to go to, say "123", and call

```
context.gotoScreen(context.getScreenById("123"));
```

in a script, for example the validation expression of another screen.

Comment: Is this solution also possible for the "Display Progress" screen when a running action failed? So I have a screen to collect some data and during the "validation" executerd by some actions I want to show the progress display. When any error occurred the previous screen should be shown again to let the user modify his input data and start the validation again.